# Variable not working with Awk to show end of file

Tags: awk

I want to display the events in a file after a certain time. I have a bash shell variable $DateMin as shown below that I am passing to awk:

`echo | awk -v Date="$DateMin" '{print Date}'`

2023-04-28 11:2

The following works where I specify the same string that is in the variable:

`tac file.log | awk -v Date="$DateMin" '!flag; /2023-04-28 11:2/{flag = 1};' | tac`

But when I try to used the Date variable, it doesn't work. It appears to show the entire file:

`tac file.log | awk -v Date="$DateMin" '!flag; /Date/{flag = 1};' | tac`

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Comment: please update the question with a (small) sample input file

Comment: if the file contains 2x rows ... `2023-04-28 11:20` and `2023-04-28 11:25` .... this code will only print the `2023-04-28 11:25` line; is that what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable in `/.../`. You need:

```
awk -v var="$date" '$0 ~ var'
```

`~` is the regex *match operator*.

Comment: I'm sure your right, but I don't understand your response enough to make it useful. Do you have an example of how to accomplish my objective with this information?

Comment: **Test it** instead of `/Date/` use `'$0 ~ date'`

Comment: I tried this, but it it shows the events from the start of the file:

`tac file.log | awk -v Date="$DateMin" '!flag; /$0 ~ Date/ {flag=1};'|tac`

Comment: Oh! Got it. Thanks.
`tac file.log | awk -v Date="$DateMin" '!flag; $0 ~ Date {flag=1};'|tac`